# Show categories, sub-categories and sub-sub categories using php

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I am working on a website and that website and want to display categories > sub-categories > sub-sub categories.

Category is showing. But i wanna display sub-category too.

Here is category code

```
  <select>
        <option>Select Category</option>
              <?php 
              $query="select * from mydb";
              $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
              while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
              {
              ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $r['id']?>"><?php echo $r['title']?></option>                                    
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

Showing Like this  :- [image]

Wanna Displa Like this :- [image]

Comment: Do you store this kind of hierarchy in the database?

Comment: @sauerburger this is only demo. i will change it. If you know how to display sub-category then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a way to store the hierarchy of categories in your database. An easy way (and certainly not the best way, since it relies on the ordering) is to add a integer column to the table specifying how many "sub"-prefixes the category has. I assume this column is called `level`.

Secondly, the desired output uses check boxes and not an option list. To get this kind of category/sub-category output you can try:

```
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 0px" /> Category <br />
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 20px" /> Sub-Category <br />
```

To generate something like the above, replace your code with

```
<?php 
$query="select * from mydb";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $id = $r['id'];
    $indent = $r['level'] * 20;
    $title = $r['title'];
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$id\" style=\"margin-left: ${indent}px\" />$title<br />";    
}                              
?>
```

I recommend adding another column (e.g. `my_order`) and add replace the query with `select * from mydb order by my_order asc` to control the ordering of the categories.